# How to make Chrome address bar show bookmark URLs when searching bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-bookmarks

See the following screenshot, when I wanted to search bookmarks (triggered by the [@bookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EolzD.png) *search engine*) with keyword `nvim`, only the 3rd bookmark's URL (with title "Getting Started with Neovim | ...") is displayed to the right side of the bookmark title. I'd like it to show  URLs for **all** matched bookmarks because it's not easy to tell who's who based only on the bookmark titles.

---

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.